# Brand verification done successfully but Actions on google console still says: is a reserved brand name. Verify ownership here

Tags: actions-on-google

I am creating a Google Action for my client. When I set the invocation name Action on Google tole me: XXXXXX is a reserved brand name. Verify ownership here.

After this I asked my client to connect the Webiste and the App with the Action and the console show that both, Website and App are connected.

Now if I go back to set the invocation name it still says: XXXXXXX is a reserved brand name. Verify ownership here.

I searched for this on the internet and found out I need to connect with the AoG support team. How do I do that?